# Statistics: Understanding confidence interval

Tags: statistics, regression, r

In R I have used `lm()`to fit a model. Then I use the `confint()` function to learn more about the slope. How to I understand the following result? Is the following conclusion true:

**With 95% probability the slope is between 1232.44 and 1259.912?**

```
> confint(fit1)
              2.5 %    97.5 %
(Intercept) 14161.38 14649.096
car.sales     1232.44  1259.912
```

Comment: You may find it helpful to look at Cross Validated SE where there has been extensive discussion of the interpretation of confidence intervals, eg here (http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/26450/why-does-a-95-confidence-interval-ci-not-imply-a-95-chance-of-containing-the)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a basic statistics question with no economics content.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately not, as in frequentist statistics the true slope is not a random variable.  This leads to a bit of a mouthful as the conclusion

What you could say is that if your assumptions are correct (such as a linear relationship with random errors) and you repeated the exercise with new sample data and new regressions, $95\%$ of the confidence intervals you would generate for the slope would contain the true value

So you have one interval from a procedure which generates correct intervals $95\%$ of the time